# Проблемы с JsSnow

Tags: javascript

Поставил на сайт jssnow, снежок падает как полагается, но изображение в хедере стало поддергиваться. Вот живой пример http://www.riviera.kharkov.ua/. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что за цифра в <head> выводится на экран? и по проблеме - у мну норм все, ничего не дергается

Comment: Отключил ваш снежок, сайт начал летать, проблема в самом скрипте. он сильно грузит комп.